# Columns to Rows in Sql Server with multiple data

Tags: sql-server

please help.. please see example data below and the desired output..

Data:

```
EmployeeID    Date        In          Out
00001         01/01/2018 | 07:00 AM | 05:00 PM
00001         01/02/2018 | 07:00 AM | 05:00 PM
00001         01/03/2018 | 07:00 AM | 05:00 PM
00002         01/01/2018 | 07:00 AM | 05:00 PM
00002         01/02/2018 | 07:00 AM | 05:00 PM
00002         01/03/2018 | 07:00 AM | 05:00 PM
```

Desired Output

```
EmployeeID    01/01/2018         |  01/02/2018         |  01/03/2018
00001         07:00 AM - 05:00PM |  07:00 AM - 05:00PM |  07:00 AM - 05:00PM
00002         07:00 AM - 05:00PM |  07:00 AM - 05:00PM |  07:00 AM - 05:00PM
```

Comment: you can find many solution in SO. Keyword is `pivot`. If you know already about it. then what you tried yet..?

Comment: I've tried but i didn't get desired output

Comment: Next time upload what you tried..

Comment: noted on this sir

Comment: Thx..im not sir I am just 23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017):

```
WITH Src AS
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES 
  ('00001' ,'01/01/2018', '07:00 AM', '05:00 PM'),
  ('00001' ,'01/02/2018', '07:00 AM', '05:00 PM'),
  ('00001' ,'01/03/2018', '07:00 AM', '05:00 PM'),
  ('00002' ,'01/01/2018', '07:00 AM', '05:00 PM'),
  ('00002' ,'01/02/2018', '07:00 AM', '05:00 PM'),
  ('00002' ,'01/03/2018', '07:00 AM', '05:00 PM')) T(EmployeeID,[Date],[In],[Out])
)
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT EmployeeID, [Date], [In]+' - '+[Out] [In] FROM Src) T
PIVOT (MAX([In]) FOR [Date] IN ([01/01/2018],[01/02/2018],[01/03/2018])) AS P
```

Comment: how can i dynamically call something like this sir..
 `declare @xxx nvarchar(200) = '01/01/2018'`
`select @xxx from pivot`