# Retrieve data from SQL Server Pivot using Web Service Method

Tags: sql-server

I had an output like this
in relation to [Columns to Rows in Sql Server with multiple data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52273327/columns-to-rows-in-sql-server-with-multiple-data)

```
EmployeeID    01/01/2018         |  01/02/2018         |  01/03/2018
00001         07:00 AM - 05:00PM |  07:00 AM - 05:00PM |  07:00 AM - 05:00PM
00002         07:00 AM - 05:00PM |  07:00 AM - 05:00PM |  07:00 AM - 05:00PM
```

The Question is how can i call the field name in Web Service
Here is my code

```
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                my_cs var = new my_cs ();
                var.DTRDate = rdr["01/01/2018"].ToString();
                var.DTRDate = rdr["01/02/2018"].ToString();
                var.DTRDate = rdr["01/03/2018"].ToString();
                mylist.Add(var);
            }
            con.Close();
```

It says:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: "01/01/2018" at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)

need help..

Comment: did you debug rdr content? btw you are saving all 3 dates on the same variable overwriten first 2 and getting only the last one

Comment: Do you need to escape `/` i.e. `/` -> `//`?

Comment: yes.. it says 
An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: I mean the content of rdr after `rdr.Read()` and before the `.ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you have the error, I assume the fields have a different name you are expecting.

You can debug rdr to check what are the field name or check this question:

[Can you get the column names from a SqlDataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681653/can-you-get-the-column-names-from-a-sqldatareader)

But you can always access fields by index

```
 while (rdr.Read())
        {
            my_cs var = new my_cs ();
            var.DTRDate1 = rdr[0].ToString();
            var.DTRDate2 = rdr[1].ToString();
            var.DTRDate3 = rdr[2].ToString();
            mylist.Add(var);
        }
```

Comment: i want DTRdate to be dynamic base on the given date of pivot sql server

Comment: then use index instead of field name